# Angular bind value to an editor

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce

I am using tinymce. I am receiving error can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'editor'. (" . How do we solve this one ? . I tried using [value]="question.notes | stringifyNote  " but it causes that error. How we can bind it using value ? Thank you.

#Code (editor) - which [value] does not work

```
<editor class="mat-input-element" matInput [value]="question.notes | stringifyNote  " [init]="tinyMCEConfig"> </editor>
```

#Code - binding on text area which works fine

```
<textarea matInput
                            cdkTextareaAutosize
                            [value]="question.notes | stringifyNote"
                            [disabled]="true"
                          ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the result you've received, `value` is not a known property of `editor`. The value you will need to insert a value into the editor is `initialValue`.

```
<editor
  initialValue="Once upon a time..."
></editor>
```

Please review the [TinyMCE Angular documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular/#initialvalue) for more details on how to use this property.

Comment: Hi sir thanks , can I integrate it with my text area? so that I no longer have to change or move the text area.

Comment: or put it inside matform fiel ?

Comment: Depends, are you wanting it to be disabled initially or at a certain point of behaviour?